# Git removing upstream from local repository

Tags: git, repository, git-fetch

I am working with a ruby on rails application and I am trying to sync a fork. It is worth mentioning that I am also on a Mac. I committed the following action:

```
$ git remote -v
```

to get a view of my local repository. I messed up when trying to go `upstream`:

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/foo/repo.git
```

When I should have capitalized Foo:

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/Foo/repos.git
```

The question is how do I remove the `upstream` because every time I try and change this it comes back with creating a `fatal` error?

Comment: It's not removing of an upstream. It's removing of a remote which so happened was named by you "upstream".

Answer (score 219):

Using git version 1.7.9.5 there is no "remove" command for remote. Use "rm" instead.

```
$ git remote rm upstream
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/Foo/repos.git
```

or, as noted in the previous answer, set-url works.

I don't know when the command changed, but Ubuntu 12.04 shipped with 1.7.9.5.

**edit**: a few people seem to have run into a situation where they do not have an "upstream" remote. execute `cat .git/config` and look at the name of the remote(s). (if on windows and not using powershell you can use `type .git/config`.)

the output will show the remotes configured for your git repo, e.g.,

```
[remote "origin"]
```

substitute the name of the remote you wish to remove as:

```
$ git remote rm origin
```

if you don't have the "upstream" remote, you can't remove it.

Comment: On Windows, it returns the error `usage: git remote remove <name>` but doesn't remove the upstream.

Comment: it returns that when you execute `git remote rm upstream`? thanks - i don't use windows much for development.

Comment: fatal: No such remote: 'upstream'

Comment: 'git remote rm master'  gives me "fatal: No such remote: 'master'"

Answer (score 43):

git remote manpage is pretty straightforward:

- https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html

Use

```
Older (backwards-compatible) syntax:
$ git remote rm upstream
Newer syntax for newer git versions: (* see below)
$ git remote remove upstream

Then do:    
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/Foo/repos.git
```

or just update the URL directly:

```
$ git remote set-url upstream https://github.com/Foo/repos.git
```

or if you are comfortable with it, just update the .git/config directly - you can probably figure out what you need to change (left as exercise for the reader).

```
...
[remote "upstream"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
    url = https://github.com/foo/repos.git
...
```

===

* Regarding 'git remote rm' vs 'git remote remove' - this changed around git [1.7.10.3](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote/1.7.10.3) / [1.7.12 2](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote/1.7.12.2) - see

https://code.google.com/p/git-core/source/detail?spec=svne17dba8fe15028425acd6a4ebebf1b8e9377d3c6&r=e17dba8fe15028425acd6a4ebebf1b8e9377d3c6

```
Log message

remote: prefer subcommand name 'remove' to 'rm'

All remote subcommands are spelled out words except 'rm'. 'rm', being a
popular UNIX command name, may mislead users that there are also 'ls' or
'mv'. Use 'remove' to fit with the rest of subcommands.

'rm' is still supported and used in the test suite. It's just not
widely advertised.
```

Comment: This answer seems to require updating. In git 1.7.9, `git remote remove upstream` produces 'error: Unknown subcommand: remove'

Comment: try 'git remote rm upstream`

Answer (score 34):

In git version 2.14.3,

You can remove upstream using

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

The above command will also remove the tracking stream branch, hence if you want to rebase from repository you have use

```
git rebase origin master
```

instead of `git pull --rebase`

Comment: This worked perfectly for my branch with 2 different upstreams

Comment: This answer seems the good one in 2022

Answer (score 31):

```
$ git remote remove <name>
```

ie.

```
$ git remote remove upstream
```

that should do the trick

Comment: As of 2023 this is the easiest and most straightforward way imo